# Angular Material reactive form: showing different error messages for every validator

Tags: angular

I have a reactive form and I want to show different error messages with `<mat-error>`, but I don't know how. I searched already a bit.

TS:

```
  selectDataFormGroup: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    headerCoordinate: ['', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern(/^.+:.+$/)
      ]
    ],
    contentCoordinate: ['', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern(/^.+:.+$/)
      ]
    ],
  });
```

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field fxFlex>
  <input matInput formControlName="headerCoordinate">
  <mat-error>{{ 'Field is required' | translate }}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

I need different error messages for `required` and `pattern`. `<mat-error>` shows up when the form field is not valid in general. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try something like this :

```html
<mat-form-field fxFlex>
  <input matInput formControlName="headerCoordinate">
  <mat-error *ngIf="selectDataFormGroup.get('headerCoordinate').hasError('required')">{{ 'Field is required' | translate }}</mat-error>
  <mat-error *ngIf="selectDataFormGroup.get('headerCoordinate').hasError('pattern')">{{ 'Field do not have the right format' | translate }}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```